# Why wont my button redirect to new URL after onload and timeout is complete?

Tags: javascript, redirect, button, timer, onload

Can a visible timer be added under the button? I'm using this code to limit access to the next page after it, I'd like to have pages before one another to have equal or more time depending on the content.  My knowledge of code is very weak I've spent 3 hours trying all kinds of websites and combinations to fix the redirect issue nevermind adding the timer. HELP!

Why won't script redirect to new URL when clicked? Can i add a visible timer under the button? If so how?

My goal is to have the onload timeout finish and the button be clickable if im really lucky a visable timer under.

```
<body onload = "setTimeout('enable()', 5000)">

<input type = "button" id = "reload" value = "Disabled" onclick = "disable()" disabled>

<script type = "text/javascript">
function enable() {
var x = document.getElementById("reload");
x.value = "Reload";
x.disabled = false;
}

function disable() {
var x = document.getElementById("reload");

"location.href = www.mysite.com"

x.value = "Disabled";
x.disabled = true;
setTimeout('enable()', 5000);
}

</script>
```

I added "location.href = www.mysite.com" in effort to get the site to redirect to the new URL. If working When your at page A you wait 5 seconds (or longer) and the button allows you to view the next page B rinse and repeat adding this script to each page.

Comment: The script you posted is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: @FastSnail I pointed out the same thing in the past, but I was proven wrong - apparently setTimeout will accept a string due to compatibility reasons for legacy code/browsers. It is unwise to use a string....but it is technically possible. Even then - it should probably be 'enable', not 'enable()'. Just an FYI though I guess.

Comment: @matmo ohh tnx.you are right.i never new that.so the actual problem is `"location.href = www.mysite.com id="reload"` but it seems `enable()` is right not `enable`

Comment: script, works as i would like, exect once it says reload, id like the click to go to a new URL Entirely. Not sure what to add to it,

Comment: <body onload = "setTimeout('enable()', 5000)">

<input type = "button" id = "reload" value = "Disabled" onclick = "disable()" disabled>

<script type = "text/javascript">
function enable() {
var x = document.getElementById("reload");
x.value = "Reload";
x.disabled = false;
}

function disable() {
var x = document.getElementById("reload");

// do whatever is required when button clicked

x.value = "Disabled";
x.disabled = true;
setTimeout('enable()', 5000);
}

</script>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but you can try something like following using iframe

```js
    function enable() {
    var x = document.getElementById("reload");
    x.value = "Reload";
    x.disabled = false;
    }

    function disable() {
    var x = document.getElementById("reload");
   var myframe1 = document.getElementById("myframe");

    myframe.src = "http://www.example.com";

    x.value = "Disabled";
    x.disabled = true;
    setTimeout('enable()', 5000);
    }
```

```html
    <body onload = "setTimeout('enable()', 5000)">
    <input type = "button" id = "reload" value = "Disabled" onclick = "disable()" disabled>
      <br/>
      <iframe id="myframe" src="http://www.test.com">    </iframe>
      </body>
```